# FormatAttribute needs forward slash for action without parameter

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, routes, asp.net-routing

I have a GET method without parameter  and want below to work

> /api/books.xml

This however works with forward slash

> /api/books/.xml

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class BooksController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Route(".{format}")]
    [FormatFilter]
    public ActionResult<List<Book>> Get()
    {
        return bookService.Get();
    }
}
```

Possible solutions that I tried are

1. Annotating without {id}

   ```
   [Route("[controller]/[action].{format}")] // no slash between [action] and .{format}
   ```
2. Adding a default route in Startup.cs without {id}, so that if id parameter is not passed like in this problem then the routing should not expect a slash after {action}.

   ```
   app.UseMvc(routes =>
       {
           routes.MapRoute(
               name: "default",
               template: "{controller}/{action=Index}");
       });
   ```

Comment: What you describe is by design. Show the controller definition along with any associated attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the currently defined routes on the controller, what you describe is by design.

Consider changing the routes to match the desired URL format

```
[ApiController]
public class BooksController : ControllerBase {        
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("api/[controller].{format}")] //<--- GET api/books.xml
    [FormatFilter]
    public ActionResult<List<Book>> Get() {
        return bookService.Get();
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried it, but then nothing works, /api/books(405), /api/books/.xml(405), /api/books.xml(404). Probably need to implement custom Route handler/middleware using  app.UseRouter(new MyRouter()); MyRoute class should implement Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.IRouter.

Comment: @ArvindSingh What is your current `BooksController`, I made a test with the solution from Nkosi, it works with `https://localhost:44330/api/books.xml`. What is your .net core version? Share us the content for `Startup.cs`.